# Text data encoding error for csv format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am trying to import the data and facing issue with the encoding.

Some times utf-8 works but not latin-1, similarly it depends on the type of data coming.

Different encoding used -
latin-1, utf-8, windows-1252

Code -

```
pd.read_csv(dir_in+file_note,sep='|',
              low_memory=False,header=0,
              error_bad_lines=False,
              encoding = "windows-1252",
              warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Please guide on how to make the code dynamic so that if one gives error it should try the other one.

1) Priority one will be utf-8

2) Priority two will be latin-1

3) Priority three will be windows-1252

Comment: would you upload the csv( or part of it), and add link

Comment: Try loading the csv with all 3 of the encodings you mentioned in that order & catch any errors that occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very beautiful, but it works.

```py
try:
  pd.read_csv(dir_in+file_note,sep='|',
                low_memory=False,header=0,
                error_bad_lines=False,
                encoding = "utf-8",
                warn_bad_lines=False)
except:
  try:
    pd.read_csv(dir_in+file_note,sep='|',
                  low_memory=False,header=0,
                  error_bad_lines=False,
                  encoding = "latin-1",
                  warn_bad_lines=False)
  except:
    pd.read_csv(dir_in+file_note,sep='|',
                  low_memory=False,header=0,
                  error_bad_lines=False,
                  encoding = "windows-1252",
                  warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked on the [github dev page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27655):

> Is there a way pandas can read a csv file and find out the encoding
>   automatically . Or is there a fix to this? Maybe to be a feature (if
>   it does not exist yet) in a future release?

One contributor says:

> This seems out of scope for pandas. I'd recommend using a library like
>   [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) to determine the encoding ahead of time.

Comment: Actually, I created the data using SPSS stream and choose the output format as utf-8. But when imported the data in notebook, it gives error.  Will definitely explore chardet, thank you.

Comment: What kind of error exactly ? Please be more specific. If you always export the files in a specific encoding there should be no surprise and no need to guess the encoding.